# jquery, disable drag and drop on top of another draggable

Tags: jquery, colors, drag-and-drop, grid

I'm trying to make a basic drag and drop interface with divs, I have all of the div's and grid working but I can't seem to figure out what the code would be to either keep draggables from being dropped on one another or to only allow a draggable to be dropped where there is empty space. any help?

Comment: can you post a (non-)working jsfiddle?

Comment: not sure what a jsfiddle is :( but here is the link to the app, as you can see the boxes just revert because I have them set to do so but I want them to stay where there is whitespace i.e. no draggable item. http://www.kendalharland.com/blog/dragndrop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a drag-and-drop tutorial: http://www.ericbieller.com/2010/06/24/how-to-create-a-simple-drag-and-drop-with-jquery/

If you need a more specific answer, you'll need to ask a more specific question (with code).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

1. Create a class for all the droppables elements `.cDrop` and another one for the draggables `.cDrags`.
2. Use an anonymous function call similar to this one for drops:

   ```
   $('.cDrop').each(function(){
       $(this).droppable({
           drop: function(event, ui) {
               if((ui.draggable.isDroppedOverOtherDrag())){
                       $(ui.draggable).draggable('option','revert','valid');
               }else{
                      //You do here whatever you need to do. For expample:         
                       alert('Good Job!!');

               }
           }
       });
   });
   ```
3. Use an anonymous function call similar to this one for drags:

   ```
   $( ".selector" ).draggable({
       start: function(event, ui) {
           $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');

       }
   });
   ```

This way you just "say" when the draggable has to be reverted (this is, when it hasn't be dropped on the right place).

The `isDroppedOverOtherDrag()` function will return true if the drag that has being dropped is over another drag. It will return false otherwise. To implement it you should use the current position of the ui.draggable object, the position of the rest of drags that has already been dropped properly and their widths/heights. Adding some code to the drop function and having a smart use of drags' ids will let you have a var with the drags that has already been dropped properly into a particular drop.

Hope it helps